# Sum over solutions of a Pell-like equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, pell-type-equations

I am given an equation of the form $$a^2 - Nb^2 = -4Nd,$$ where $N$ and $d$ are fixed positive numbers and $N$ is not a square. I would like to calculate the series $$\sum_{a,b} (|a|-\sqrt{N}|b|)$$ taken over all integer solutions. (Assuming it converges at all!) *Solutions with $a$=0 should be counted twice.*

Example: Consider the equation $$a^2 - 3b^2 = -12.$$ The solutions are $$a = \pm \sqrt{3} \Big( (2 + \sqrt{3})^n - (2 - \sqrt{3})^n \Big), \; n \in \mathbb{Z}$$ with $$b = \pm \Big( (2 + \sqrt{3})^n + (2 - \sqrt{3})^n \Big),$$ so $$|a| - \sqrt{3} |b| = -2 \sqrt{3} (2 - \sqrt{3})^n$$ for positive $n$ and $$|a| - \sqrt{3} |b| = -2 \sqrt{3} (2 + \sqrt{3})^n$$ for negative $n$, so \begin{align*} \sum_{a,b} (|a| - \sqrt{N} |b|) &= -8 \sqrt{3} - 8 \sqrt{3} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (2 - \sqrt{3})^n - 8 \sqrt{3} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (2 + \sqrt{3})^{-n} \\ &= -8 \sqrt{3} - 8 \sqrt{3} \frac{\sqrt{3} - 1}{2} - 8 \sqrt{3} \frac{1}{1 + \sqrt{3}} \\ &= - 24. \end{align*}

Example: Consider the equation $$a^2 - 12b^2 = -12 \cdot 16.$$ The solutions are $$a = \pm 4 \sqrt{3} \Big( (7 - 4 \sqrt{3})^n - (7 + 4 \sqrt{3})^n \Big)$$ and $$b = 2 \Big( (7 - 4 \sqrt{3})^n + (7 + 4 \sqrt{3})^n \Big).$$ As above, we get $$\sum_{a,b} (|a| - \sqrt{12} |b|) = -16 \sqrt{3} - 16 \sqrt{3} \Big( \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} - \frac{1}{2} \Big) - 16 \sqrt{3} \Big( \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} - \frac{1}{2} \Big) = -32.$$
**Question:** Is the result always an integer, and can we calculate it without finding all solutions $a,b$?